# Являются ли папки с исходным и выходным кодом "приложением" в проектах использованием Docker?

Tags: docker, терминология

Если раньше мои Full-Stack проекты подразделялись на папку для исходных файлов и папку для выходных файлов (такое подразделение естественно ввиду того, что исходный код я пишу на TypeScript), а файлы с метаданными и конфигурациями, такие как `package.json` были в корне проекта, то при переходе проектов на Docker организацию файлов, видимо, придётся пересмотреть.

Вот один из найденный мной примеров, в котором всё то, что раньше у меня лежало в корне проекта, теперь находится в `docker/webpack`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут же возникла путаница с терминологией: если раньше я с *приложением* отождествлял папку с проектом, то теперь в папке проекта будут и базы данных, и ещё всякие разные сервисы.

Таким образом, я теперь знаю следующие значения термина *(веб)-приложения* :

1. Совокупность всех компонентов, таких как базы данных и микросервисы, а так же собранный исходный код прикладной логики. Ради примера позаимствовал [схему из урока по Kubernetes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qmac8MNlhmg&ab_channel=ITSumma), то есть в этом значении "приложением" называют в совокупности всё то, что на схеме нарисовано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Результирующee интерактивное отображение в браузере,. (Например, когда рекламщик делает скриншоты UI и говорит "попробуйте новое приложение").
3. Папка с исходным и/или выходным кодом прикладной логики серверной части, клиентской части или обоих.

Третий вариант, как я могу предположить, в контексте Docker-а уже не употребляется.

Среди тех примеров, что я видел, папки (соответствующие Image-ам) с серверной и клиентской частью называют крайне неочевидными именами, такими как `webpack` или `web`. А если сборку проекта осуществляет не только webpack, а ещё gulp?

Итак, вопрос: что же называется "приложением" в контексте Docker-проекта и как называют папку с прикладной логикой приложения (в отличие от папок с базой данных и сторонними сервисами).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала хотел бы отметить для будущих читателей: **Приложение, завёрнутое в докер ничем не отличается от приложения, выложенного на обычную виртуалку** *(за исключением способа развертывания)*. Docker контейнер — это способ передачи и дальнейшей оркестрации (в некотором смысле)

Я бы взял за основу понимание, **что приложение** — *это набор программных компонентов и кода с компилятором (интерпретатором) настроенных на совместную работу для выполнения заложенных (требуемых) функций.*

Теперь немного о Docker... В вопросе фигурирует понятие "папок", что меня немного смутило. Я предлагаю рассмотреть функцию докера (лучше сказать утилиту) - [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).
Это специальный файл и утилита его запуска для старта нескольких контейнеров с определенной зависимостью.

*Например, чтобы приложение заработало, нужно поднять БД, кеш, MTA, nodeJS, nginx и ещё какой-нибудь бэк. Если поднимать всё руками - потребуется ввести с десяток команд перед тем, как всё заработает (когда и если :). Вместо этого придуманы специальные инструкции, которые поднимают компоненты (контейнеры Docker) с определенными параметрами*

**Именно наличие такой утилиты даёт возможность говорить, что к рамках поставки функционала приложение представляет собой набор компонент.**
[image: Пример разделения приложения на компоненты]

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! "В вопросе фигурирует понятие "папок", что меня немного смутило." - речь идёт о том, накладывает ли какие-нибудь ограничения Docker на структуру проекта. Вот пример конфликтной ситуации: у нас есть папка с исходным кодом и сборкой обычного  full-stack веб-приложения, а также папка с базой данных MySQL. "Обычного" означает, что никаких баз данных внутри корневой папки с кодом быть не должно. В этом случае, когда мы открываем проект в IDE, то всё выглядит так, что Docker-а вообще нет. Но ведь нам нужна база данных для приложения. Это значит, что придётся реорганизовать

Comment: приложение, так, чтобы Docker знал и о собранном приложении, и о базе данных. Я видел для только один шаблон: общая папка под проект, в нём `docker-compose.yaml`, папка для кода и папка для базы данных. Теперь мы не можем запускать сборку приложения из папки для кода, где находится `package.json`, как это было раньше. Теперь сборку проектов вместе с базой данных должен выполнять Docker из корневой папки проекта. Я где-нибудь ошибся?

Comment: Докер не выполняет сборку проекта. Это всё должно делаться внутри контейнера. Посмотрите синтаксис и применение Dockerfile.
Кажется, что Вы делаете велосипед с квадратными колесами.

Comment: "Это всё должно делаться внутри контейнера." - чтобы "это всё" было внутри контейнера, нам нужно, чтобы внутри контейнера были исходные файлы и файлы настроек утилит сборки проекта (ну или объясните пожалуйста, как это может быть по-другому). Но ведь когда собранное приложение запущено, нам всё это становится не нужным! Нам нужны только собранные скрипты, откомпилированные стили и разметка (когда они написаны на препроцессорах) и оптимизированные изображения, а исходного кода в контейнере, созданного на сервере, нам не нужно.