# Замена npm-ссылок в Docker-контейнере (случай для образа “node:12.4” и файла“docker-compose”)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

После долгих изысканий о том, как лучше организовать инкрементальную сборку проекта в условиях локальной разработки для проекта с Docker-ом, я выбрал такое концептуальное решение:

**Наличие Docker-а никак не должно влиять на работу инструментов для
сборки проекта (gulp, webpack и т. д.), в частности навязывать новую
файловую структуру проекта.**

Я думаю, ввиду мнения специалиста @GrayHoax, такая концепция имеет право на существование:

> Приложение, завёрнутое в докер ничем не отличается от приложения,
> выложенного на обычную виртуалку (за исключением способа развертывания).
>
> [Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1189135/193415)

### Проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В проекте имеется несколько зависимостей (допустим `dependency_a` и `dependency_b`), доступ которым осуществляется с помощью инструмента [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna). Для тех, кто с ним не знаком, скажу что судя по всему этот инструмент использует обычные npm-сысылки, а сам лишь только автоматизирует процесс их добавления.

Как бы Вы не критиковали структуру моего проекта за её непохожесть на обычный src/dest-шаблон, без Docker-а сборка проекта работает и собранное full-stack приложение помещается в папку `02-DevelopmentBuild` (для режима локальной разработки).

Теперь нужно поместить этот проект в Docker-контейнер **без прямого копирования**, причем пути Docker должен правильно понять ссылки `dependency_a` и `dependency_b`.

Теперь, со следующим `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  logic:
    image: node:12.4
    command: npm run 'SPA incremental building' && npm run 'Run server'
    volumes:
      - .:/Application
    working_dir: /Application
```

Кстати, именно этот способ обеспечения доступа к локальным файлом мне порекомендовали в ответе на вопрос [Как правильно объявлять Volum-ы в длинном синтаксисе Docker-а?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1200227/193415). Увы, этот способ не учитывает npm-ссылки, потому возникает ошибка:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/packages/dependency_a/bin/dependency_a'.
```

Директория `packages` находится на уровень выше проекта, но возможно это для Lerna это не столько директория, сколько алиас.

На всякий случай покажу, как это выглядит в косоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другими словами, Docker не видит npm-ссылку, актуальную для файловой системы локального компьютера.

### Концепция решения

1. С точки зрения NPM и Lerna у меня всё сделано правильно ввиду того, что без Docker-а сборка проекта работает. Но это "правильно" для Docker-контейнера неактуально.
2. Docker не должен навязывать условий, соблюдение которых поломает обычную сборку проекта без Docker-а (это что будет если каждый инструмент, будь то Docker, Gulp или Webpack начнут навязывать свои структуры проекта и так далее).
3. Таким образом, Docker должен предоставлять функционал (API), который позволит объяснить **только ему**, где же надо искать `dependency_a` и другие.

### Попытки решения без понимания

Ввиду того, что я задаю этот вопрос, я не знаю, как надо делать правильно, потому я эксперимента ради попробовал такое решение:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  logic:
    image: node:12.4
    command: npm run 'SPA incremental building' && npm run 'Run server'
    volumes:
      - .:/Application
      - ../../packages/dependency_a:/Application/node_modules/dependency_a
      - ../../packages/dependency_b:/Application/node_modules/dependency_a
    working_dir: /Application
#    ports:
#      - "3000:3000"
```

Естественно, оно нерабочее. Вдобавок к этому, я не совсем понял, что сделал. Наконец, я и сам чувствую, что создание пересекающихся bind-ов (или создание одного поверх другого) - это что-то не то.

Сообщение об ошибке то же, что и раньше.

### Анализ статьи о подобной проблеме

Подобная ситуация рассматривается в статье [Developing a new Node module in a Docker container without using NPM link](https://properdesign.co.uk/developing-a-new-node-module-in-a-docker-container-without-using-npm-link/). Вот какое решение она предлагает:

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/node_modules
 
ENV PATH /usr/src/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
volumes:
- .:/usr/src/app
- ../redux-beacon-slack:/usr/src/node_modules/redux-beacon-slack
```

Оно мне не подходит в первую очередь потому, что у меня образ другой, не операционной системы, а `node:12.4`.

### Недопустимые решения

#### Использовать только опубликованные npm библиотеки

**Удобно организованная среда разработки является базовым требованием современной IT-индустрии.** Применительно к `npm` это значит:

1. Не должно быть никаких лишних релизов `npm`-библиотек ("чтобы просто посмотреть отладочную информацию").
2. Если мы внесли какое-либо изменение в локально разрабатываемую npm-зависимость, то мы должны в реальном времени получать обратную связь от этого. Например, добавили `console.log()` в зависимость - тут же видим вывод в консоль при запуске основного приложения.

#### Изменение структуры проекта

ИМХО хороший инструмент должен адаптироваться под структуру уже существующих проектов, а не навязывать свою собственную.

#### Насчет Dockerfile

Как видите, его в проекте нет. Увидев [пример без Docker файла](https://github.com/ishidait/docker-nodejs/tree/blog-3), я решил убрать Dockerfile и добавить его снова только если на то будет рациональная причина.

#### Часто задаваемый вопрос: зачем мне Docker?

Нужен он мне собственно затем, зачем его и разрабатывали:

1. Не зависеть от версии локально установленного NodeJS.
2. Избежать полностью ручной установки NodeJS и других инструментов (например, баз данных) при деплое на продакшен.

В данном приложении заменить локальный Node.JS на Docker-образ - это лишь первый шаг, далее я буду добавлять образ с базой данных.

#### О копировании файлов

На англоязычном StackOverflow первый конкурс на английскую версию этого вопроса закончился без ответа. В комментариях люди что-то постоянно говорили про копирование файлов.

Этот момент я прояснил в вопросах [Есть ли в Docker-e концепция доступа к локальным файлам без их прямого копирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1199800/193415) b [Как правильно объявлять Volum-ы в длинном синтаксисе Docker-а?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1200227/193415) и вот какой вердикт: **в режиме локальной разработки ничего копировать не надо**, потому что такой принцип нарушит инкрементальную сборку, то есть автоматическую пересборку проекта **в реальном времени** при внесении изменений в исходный код и автоматическую перезагрузку страницы браузера при обновлении сборки. Вместо этого, нужно обеспечить доступ к проекту из Docker-контейнера (это уже достигнуто обычным bind-ом) и теперь объяснить ему, как интерпретировать неактуальные для него npm-сыылки.

Comment: `это что будет если каждый инструмент...`


Но Вы же уже завязались на условия, навязанные Lerna)

Comment: @Niki-Timofe А какие условия навязывает Lerna? Но даже если они есть, я не против от них отвязаться, если есть лучшие альтернативы Lerna.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема у вас можно логи ошибки ( не картинкой) ? Я собираю мульти языковые проекты в докере (node.js+python, node.js+go, go, typescript) без композитора через Make в ступенчатой сборке  Buildkit. Конечный контейнер содержит только скомпилированные файлы без системных сзависимостей и готов к запуску деплоим на AWS ECR/ECS. Приведите пример как проект собирается локально (без IDE).

Comment: `Естественно, оно нерабочее.` - не работают по причине `..`? В `docker-compose.yml` есть инструкция context, [вот тут пример как ее использовать](https://medium.com/@manandharsabbir/docker-compose-different-build-context-path-and-dockerfile-file-path-8795a992821a). Может, поможет. `Вдобавок к этому, я не совсем понял, что сделал. Наконец, я и сам чувствую, что создание пересекающихся bind-ов (или создание одного поверх другого) - это что-то не то.`. - по-моему это нормальная практика. В линуксе это называется перемонтирование. В докере работает примерно также. Главное самому не запутаться.

Comment: Вопрос очень длинный и мне трудно понять, что вообще нужно. Для себя я понял, что вы 1) разрабатываете два npm-модуля 2) есть проект, в котором используются эти модули 3) хотите менять файлы модулей в вашем любимом редакторе, и чтобы все изменения сразу "применялись" без необходимости `docker build ...` и проблема в том, как "подружить" пакеты за пределами проекта, проект, докер и возможность локальной разработки?

Comment: @TotalPusher, "мне трудно понять, что вообще нужно" - убрать упоминаемую в вопросе ошибку без изменения структуры проекта. "разрабатываете два npm-модуля" - да, но это число не так важно. Будем считать, что этих зависимостей от 0 до *n*. 3) "хотите менять файлы модулей в вашем любимом редакторе" - нет. Концептуально, для решения задачи нужно две вещи: 1. примонтировать к Docker-у разрабатываемые зависимости (они вне корня проекта). 2. При запуске контейнера заменить актуальные для локального компьютера npm-сыылки на эти зависимости на те, которые актуальны для контейнера.

Comment: Перефразируя, нужно решить ошибку монтирования `../../packages/dependency_a:/Application/node_modules/dependency_a` который находится вне проекта для локальной разработки? И чтобы при сборке образа для продакшена этого монтирования не было, а файлы пакетов были теми, что ставит `npm install` (пакеты к этому времени будут выложены в какие-то репы типа npmjs.com)? Правильно я понял?

Comment: @TotalPusher Да. Только не знаю, правильно ли называть это "ошибкой монтирования", потому что примонтировано всё правильно, проблема лишь в том, что символическая ссылка становится неактуальной при монтированнии.

Comment: Монтирование в докере **требует** абсолютного пути к директории https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Не используйте симлинки. Симлинк "не протащит" внутрь то, на что он указывает. Это лишь указатель на место в файловой системе. А так как в докере файловая система монтируется своя, этот симлинк будет указывать внутри контейнера на не существующий файл. Вы сейчас делаете `docker-compose up ...`? Тогда добавьте в файл монтирования абсолютных путей - замените `../..` на абсолютный путь начиная с `/`. Тут сложность для новичков в том, что docker-compose и docker - разные вещи, в чем то совпадают, и это вносит путаницу. В `docker-compose.yml` можно указывать относит. и абсол. ссылки.

Comment: PS. К сожалению, почти все мануалы не объясняют как реально работает докер. Мне помогло [вот это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdVNKmru3LM). Если вы знакомы с понятием чрутинга, то докер делает очень похожие вещи

Comment: @TotalPusher, я не фанат симлинков, но какие ещё тогда есть подходы в обеспечении мгновенной обратной связи при внесении изменений в зависимость при параллельной разработке зависимости и основного проекта? (Сейчас я спрашиваю не про Docker, а вообще)

Comment: Как я понял, вы хотите не напрямую в node_modules править пакет? Тогда можно примонтировать `sudo mount --bind my_module node_modules/my_module`. Отмонтировать `sudo umount node_modules/my_module/`. Прочитать об этом можно в `man mount` секция `The bind mounts`

Answer (score 2):

> Приложение, завёрнутое в докер ничем не отличается от приложения, выложенного на обычную виртуалку

Это справедливо с оговорками и чуть ниже о них напишу, а сейчас примем это как исходный посыл. Проблема, которая у вас возникает, а именно

> Docker не видит npm-ссылку, актуальную для файловой системы локального компьютера

возникает потому, что вы не трактуете приложение в докере таким же образом, как бы вы его запускали на виртуалке в той части, что вы запускаете `npm install` или его аналог на *хосте*. Из-за этого возникают ссылки с путями на локальном хосте. Если вы проделаете такую же операцию с виртуальной машиной, т.е. установите зависимости на локальном хосте, а потом папку с приложением скопируете или примонтируете в файловую систему виртуалки, то получите ровно ту же проблему, что имеете сейчас в докере. Виртуалка или докер контейнер не знают ничего о файловой системе вашего хоста, и не могут обращаться к файлам в файловой системе хоста.

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1189134/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-docker-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/1191767) описан способ, как сделать инкрементную сборку. И важный момент там заключается в том, что инсталяция пакетов происходит *внутри* контейнера. Именно это является главной проблемой у вас сейчас.

Обратите внимание также, что в этом подходе все манипуляции с зависимостями при разработке с использованием докера (например добавление нового пакета) происходит в самом контенере командами типа:

```
docker-compose run buildchain yarn add cat-names --dev
```

В вашем случае нужно запускать соответствующие команды Lerna, но тоже внутри контейнера.

Конечно, для ускорения работы имеет смысл сконфигурировать контейнер так, чтоб `node_modules` сохранялся между запусками (т.е. использовать volume). Это все есть той статье.

Теперь что касается параллелей между виртуалкой и докером. Это правда, что нет разницы, где приложение запускается в виртуалке или в докере. Но есть большая разница используется инкрементнальная сборка или нет. В prod инсталяциях создаются неизменяемые образы. Даже если нужно внести какое-то изменение на виртуалку, то правильный подход - это пересоздать ее (возможно на основе какого-то подготовленного образа). Виртуалки а тем более докер контейнеры должны быть immutable, в чем и заключается суть [разделения на сборку и запуск](https://12factor.net/build-release-run) из 12 factor app. Запуск в инкрементальном режиме - это уже отход от того, чтобы запускать приложение в том же режиме, что и на проде. Тем более, когда у вас есть необходимость синхронизации кода между двумя хостами. И нормально и ожидаемо, что это будет влиять на способ развертывания и запуска. Вопрос только в том, чтобы сделать это по возможности безболезненно и на какие компромиссы прийдется пойти.

Comment: Снова благодарю Вас за содержательный ответ. Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос, вынесем вердикт, ссылающийся на заголовок вопроса. Первая его часть будет такой: "Тот способ, который представлен в вопросе, проблематичный, потому что  виртуальня машина или докер контейнер не знают ничего о файловой системе хоста. Для обеспечения инкрементальной сборки лучше использовать [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1191767/193415) подход.". Но отсюда не вытекает ответ на вопрос, заданный в заголовке (можно ли заменить в контейнере npm-ссылки, актуальные для локальной машины).

Comment: Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос, нужно либо объявить, что это невозможно, либо рассказать, как это возможно. Может быть, создать дополнительные Volum-ы для локальных зависимостей и программно переопределить ссылки при запуске Docker-контейнера? Может быть, в решении этого вопроса помогут сиcтемные переменные? И конечно, при окончательном деплое на продакшен будут использованы уже опубликованные npm-библиотеки.

Comment: Очевидно, что сделать можно все, вопрос как всегда в цене (грубо говоря всегда можно внутри контейнера сначала все ссылки стереть вручную и заново сделать `npm install`). Вариантов много, но трудно экспериментировать чтоб ответить по сути и конкретными командами, так как у вас нестандартная структура проекта . Приведите в вопросе пример `package.json`, который будет делать такую сборку (т.е. в отдельную папку и т.д.), я не знаком с javascript на таком уровне, чтоб быстро сообразить, как такое сделать.

Comment: `Конечно, для ускорения работы имеет смысл сконфигурировать контейнер так, чтоб node_modules сохранялся между запусками (т.е. использовать volume). Это все есть той статье.`. Зачем volume? Все делается на основе слоев докера. Для этого есть такой интересный способ: `ADD ./package.json ./package-lock.json /tmp/

RUN cd /tmp && npm install

WORKDIR srv
ADD . /srv

RUN mv /tmp/node_modules /srv`

Comment: @RomanKonoval, "package.json" не содержит никакой логики, он только может содержать консольные команды, делегирующие сборку проектов соответствующим инструментам (например gulp), поэтмоу показывать его не имеет смысла. В общем, закончим на том, что концептуально можно написать и после запуска контейнера запустить специальный скрипт, который обеспечит доступ с нужным зависимостям.

Comment: @TotalPusher, благодраю Вас за ещё одну идею. Могу я Вас попросить объяснить на словах, что имеено вы хотите сделать приведённым кодом?

Comment: Да. Вот этот код [в читаемом виде](https://gist.github.com/dbfun/355bd8ee89d21c32c5e9d57603a82462) с моими комментариями. Такую штуку я видел во многих проектах, и сначала не понимал зачем такие выкрутасы. А вот для ускорения билдежки.

Comment: PS. Нашел статью в которой раскрывается тот же самый трюк http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/

Comment: У подхода со слоями есть минус. При любом изменении в package.json будет делаться заново полный `npm install` с нуля. С volume изменение не касающееся зависимостей этого не требует, добавление новой зависимости установит только ее одну. Читайте https://mattgrayisok.com/a-craft-cms-development-workflow-with-docker-part-1-local-development

Comment: Вторая часть вердикта: "Если всё же нужно обеспечить доступ к локальной зависимости вне корня проекта, то на концептуальном уровне один из подходов такой: добавить в файл монтирования абсолютных путей" (Подход предложен @TotalPusher)