# Есть ли в Docker-e концепция доступа к локальным файлам без их прямого копирования?

Tags: docker

Вопрос [Замена npm-ссылок в Docker-контейнере (случай для образа “node:12.4” и файла“docker-compose”)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1198864/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-npm-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-docker-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-node12-4-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-doc) оказался "крепким орешком" как на русскоязычном, на и на англоязычном StackOverflow (на последнем конкурс закончился без единого ответа). Одной из причин является непонимание мной концепции Docker volum-ов.

Этот [урок по Docker для начинающих](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QF4ZF857m44&t=2765s&ab_channel=%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B2) получил высокие оценки и хвалебные комментарии, но объяснение концепции Volum-ов нуждается в серьёзной доработке:

> По сути, Docker-volume - это настройка на теми же папками (прим.:
> монтируемыми локальными папками). Просто мы создаём Docker-volume и
> прицепляем его к контейнеру. Сам Docker volume представляет собой
> папку, просто она хранится по определённому пути.

Я сделал вывод, что Docker-volume - это настройка доступа к локальным файлам из Docker-контейнера, а не их копирование. Но видимо, оно оказалось ошибочным:

> Вы по сути привязываете локальную директорию к volum-у (другими
> словами - копируете) когда добавляете двоеточие в определение
> `volumes` в файле `docker-compose`.
>
> Оригинал:
>
> You are actually binding your local directory to the volume (which
> means copying) when you add the colon : in the volumes part of the
> docker-compose file
>
> [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64519937/4818123) (см. комментарии к вопросу)

Если концепция Docker-volum-ов подразумевает копирование, то это - не то, что мне надо.
Почему? Само по себе слово "копирование" уже настораживает и сразу возникает вопрос: отразятся ли изменения на Docker-контейнере, когда в файлах, копия которых была сделана, произойдут изменения? Могу предположить, что это не так, а в режиме локальной разработки нужно, чтобы было именно так и не как иначе для обеспечения обратной связи при внесении изменений в исходный код (конкретнее: при внесении в исходный код должна происходить его автоматическая перекомпиляция и далее - перезагрузка страницы браузера).

Мне нужна концепция "ярлыков": мы даём Docker-контейнеру ссылку на корневую папку проекта (другими словами, настраиваем к ней доступ из Docker-контейнера), а эффект при этом такой, что находится эта папка в Docker-контейнере, хотя никакого копирования не было.

Есть ли в Docker такая концепция?

Comment: Всегда считал что это не копирование, а именно монтирование. Вопрос почему вы пишете что можете предположить? Ведь это очень легко проверить. Создаёте docker контейнер и прокидываете в него volume. Создаёте там файл. Заходите в контейнер. Делаете там tail -f ваш_файл. Меняете его на хосте и смотрите на вывод tail

Comment: Для этого будет достаточно примонтировать эту папку.

Comment: *Есть ли в Docker такая концепция?* — да, есть. в терминах docker-а это volume. на самом деле это банальное монтирование. ничего при этом не копируется. не забивайте себе голову, выискивая высказывания в интернетах: их можно найти на любой вкус и цвет. лучше ориентируйтесь на документацию к программе. там всё верно написано.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, благодарю Вас за комментарий! Подскажите пожалуйста, чем отличается Docker volume от простого монтирования папки?

Comment: *чем отличается Docker volume от простого монтирования папки?* — вопрос с какой-то подковыркой, да? я же уже написал выше: «на самом деле это банальное монтирование».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, понял, буду теперь знать что это одно и то же.