# Как правильно объявлять Volum-ы в длинном синтаксисе Docker-а?

Tags: docker-compose

Пример из [документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3):

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./static
        target: /opt/app/static

networks:
  webnet:

volumes:
  mydata:
```

Последние 4 строки издевательски (для новичков) опущены. Для меня, новичка в Docker на момент этого вопроса, неочевидно, чем надо заполнить это пустое значение. Если же опустить `volumes` целиком, то будет ошибка:

```
Named volume XXX is used in service "YYY" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

Если там должно быть что-то вроде:

```yaml
volumes:
 - /var/lib/mysql
 - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

то тоже возникает непонятный момент: вроде как должен быть использоваться ЛИБО длинный синтаксис, ЛИБО короткий, но если выше приведённое валидно, то получается что длинный синтаксис может использоваться только ВМЕСТЕ с коротким?

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./static
        target: /opt/app/static

networks:
  webnet: # Угадай что!

volumes:
  mydata:
   - /var/lib/mysql
   - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует несколько типов `volume`:

- `bind` это обычное монтирование ("проброс") папки из хост машины в контейнер.
- `volume` это именованная папка, которая монтируется в контейнер (возможно проще воспринимать как некий виртуальный диск, хотя по факту, это все же обычная папка, только которая находится в `/var/lib/docker/volumes`).

Также как вы и указали есть "короткий" и "длинный" синтаксис монтирования. Их можно использовать независимо друг от друга, просто длинный позволяет настроить больше параметром, но если они не нужны, то короткий просто удобнее. Например, это вполне валидный синтаксис:

```yaml
volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: mydata
    target: /data
    volume:
      nocopy: true
  - ./static:/opt/app/static
  # это равно:
  # - type: bind
  #   source: ./static
  #   target: /opt/app/static
```

В первом случае монтируется именованный `volume`, во втором происходит `bind` папки из проекта.

Также существует два место объявления `volumes` на уровне сервиса (контейнера) и на верхнем уровне. Это необходимо для того, чтобы была возможность использовать один `volume` в нескольких сервисах. Например, в вашем примере, на верхнем уровне создается "общий" `volume` с именем `mydata`:

```yaml
volumes:
  mydata:
```

а уже на уровне конкретного сервиса `web` он используется:

```yaml
volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: mydata
    target: /data
```

Т.е. этот `volume` монтируется в папку `data` внутри контейнера, но также внутри другого сервиса вы можете его примонтировать ещё раз.

> Последние 4 строки издевательски (для новичков) опущены. Для меня, новичка в Docker на момент этого вопроса, неочевидно, чем надо заполнить это пустое значение.

Это валидный синтаксис создания сети и `volume` после двоеточия (`:`) можно ничего не писать, оно будет работать.

> Если же опустить volumes целиком, то будет ошибка:

Да, это происходит из-за того, что вы используете именованный `volume`, который нигде не объявлен, собственно ошибка про это и говорит.

А вот это код уже не валиден:

```yaml
volumes:
  mydata:
   - /var/lib/mysql
   - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Т.к. после имени `mydata:` ожидаются настройки для этого `volume`, которые можно найти [тут](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference).

Comment: Благодарю Вас канонический ответ! Уже за то, что Вы всё так замечательно объяснили, я просто не имею права не дать Вам награду. Могу ли я попросить Вас в рамках этого вопроса уточнить один момент: если я хочу сделать Volum-ом корень проекта, то как объявить имя этого Volum-а?

Comment: @БоковГлеб если хотите примонтировать папку с проектом (исходный код), то именованный `volume` вам не нужен, а обычного `bind` хватит, например, на уровне сервиса: `- ./src:/usr/app/`, а на верхнем уровне ничего не нужно указывать

Comment: Благодаря Вам этот вопрос исчерпан. Следующий шаг - научить `bind` видеть npm-ссылки. Он рассматривается в вопросе [Замена npm-ссылок в Docker-контейнере (случай для образа “node:12.4” и файла“docker-compose”)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1198864/193415).