# Выполнить maven install в докер контейнере

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

У меня есть многомодульный проект на мавене.
Он достаточно древний и собирается со специальным танцем с бубном.

Примерная вид проекта

```
root
  |__api
  |__build
  |__flash
  |__gwt
  |__server
  |__service
  |__shared
  |__target
  |__toolset
```

Чтобы собрать такой проект у меня есть специальный скрипт, который нужно выполнить находясь в корне проекта.

```
./build/build_and_deploy.sh
```

При сборке на Windows возникает много проблем (проблемы с длинной путей, символы и лайн-сепараторы сбиваются и т.п.) Поэтому я хочу сделать сборку этого проекта в докере.
Сначала я хотел подключить **docker-maven-plugin** от **io.fabric8** как плагин в мавен, но я как понимаю он не может запустить сборку самого себя в докере.

Поэтому я пытался написать **Dockerfile** и столкнулся со следующими проблемами
Я не хочу копировать .m2 папку в докер, завимостей там много это будет достатчно долго.
Я не хочу копировать исходники проекта внутрь контейнера
У меня не получилось запустить скрипт  ./build/build_and_deploy.sh

Как я вижу решение данной проблемы.

1. Создать докерфайл, подключить в него maven и java8 и баш
2. С помощью Volume подключить исходники и мавен репозиторий
3. Т.к. я работаю через ВПН и деплоится скрипт должен через него нужно найти решение проблемы (проброс прокси/портов???)

Если у вас есть опыт или примеры похожего скрипта или грамотный совет, то я буду рад его услышать

Comment: вот я за один литературный талант, и выражение "со специальным танцем с бубном" (как нельзя лучше подходяшщее для многих процессов) - ставлю плюс вопросу!

Comment: План нормальный. Образ maven:3.8.5-jdk-8, уже содержит все что нужно. Контейнер по умолчанию имеет доступ и к ресурсам через впн. Так что нужно подключить только исходники и m2. Что-то в духе: `docker run -ti -v /path/on/host/to/myproj:/myproj -v /path/on/host/to/.m2:/root/.m2  --entrypoint /bin/bash -w "/root" maven:3.8.5-jdk-8 -c "./build/build_and_deploy.sh`

Comment: Главные подводные камни - это смешивание локальной сборки и сборки в докере. Для файлов типа *.class это не проблема, но если где-то есть генерируемые файлы с путями - это [стандартный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204027/2189710) источник проблем. Нужно делать правильный clean вначале сборки.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Большое спасибо за пример строки. Буду пробовать. Как будут новости отпишусь!